# Better way to dynamically create methods

Tags: python, dynamic, methods

So I need to mutate a method at object initialization based upon input to `__init__` (for those interested, I'm changing the `navigate_to` method in a test framework based upon which type of automator is being instantiated (Selenium, mobile device automator, etc)).  I've come up with a solution using a conditionally created closure in `__init__`, but it seems like there should be a more elegant and optimized way to do this.  As an example of the approach:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
        if x % 2:
            def odd_or_even():
                return '%d odd' % self.x
        else:
            def odd_or_even():
                return '%d even' % self.x
        self.odd_or_even = odd_or_even
```

Resulting in:

```
>>> foo1 = Foo(1)
>>> foo2 = Foo(2)
>>> foo1.odd_or_even()
'1 odd'
>>> foo2.odd_or_even()
'2 even'
```

This works, but I feel like there should be some better way to do this.  Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make a different method for each type of automator, and then a generic method that uses the state of `self` to determine which of the specific methods to call.

Why do you need to create a closure containing the decision, when you can just record the decision in `self`?

Comment: I was thinking of doing that too.  I just thought it would be nice to condense the process down to a single location.

Comment: @sr2222 Either you define it all in one place, in which case you get something like your example in the OP and are uncomfortable that it looks inelegant, or you split the specific methods from the selector logic and are uncomfortable that it's not all in one place. It's pretty much impossible to have neither discomfort.

Comment: @sr2222 The process by which I arrived at my suggestion though was to think that if you wanted to declutter `__init__`, then `even()` and `odd()` could be separate functions, and you could just store which one to call in `self.odd_or_even`. And then I realised that was pretty pointless, since you could just define an `odd_or_even` method that does `self.x % 2` to determine which one to call, and you no longer even need to store a function as an instance attribute!

Comment: yeah, when you put it that way, the catch 22 becomes pretty obvious.  :)  And of course, this is a simplified example to illustrate what I'm trying to accomplish; the logic I'm actually trying to implement cannot be condensed like that of the illustrative example.  I was more thinking if there was a way to accomplish this without using closures but still sticking it in `__init__` or some delegate method that occurs at the same point in program flow, but it seems there is not.

Comment: Even though I thought I didn't want to, I ended up going with this solution after all.  Accepted.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest delegating this - something like

```
class Automator(object):
    def navigate_to(self, url):
        pass

class SeleniumAutomator(Automator):
    def navigate_to(self, url):
        # do it the Selenium way
        pass

class MobileAutomator(Automator):
    def navigate_to(self, url):
        # do it the mobile-browser way
        pass

class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, x, automator):
        self.x = x
        self.automator = automator

    def navigate_to(self, url):
        return self.automator.navigate_to(url)

f = Foo(3, SeleniumAutomator())
f.navigate_to('http://www.someplace.org/')
```

... you could do this just with functions, but I presume there are a bunch of interface-dependent methods, and it seems cleanest to keep them grouped in a class.

**Edit:** oh - then what you want isn't a Foo, it's an automator factory - something like

```
def makeAutomator(type, *args, **kwargs):
    return {
        "selenium": SeleniumAutomator,
        "mobile":   MobileAutomator
    }[type](*args, **kwargs)

myauto = makeAutomator("selenium")
```

Comment: The thing is the point of this class is to unify the interface to a bunch of different automators.  It is true I could wrap every automator, but I think that might be overkill if I can just make a few things in the manager class change their behavior based upon what specific automator is spun up.  Another goal here also is to hide the nitty gritty from the end users of the API, so I'm trying to flatten the interface so it's not necessary for the end user to know which automator is being used under the hood.

Comment: In response to your edit, I already have that.  It's what Foo is.  :)  The thing is that this is designed to be an extensible API, so much of the simpler automator functionality is delegated to extension modules that parse views (pages) and the like.  It's just for generalized things like "go to this view", it has to be handled by the central manager, as it doesn't belong to any one view, and it applies universally across automators.

Comment: Well, to be more accurate, Foo is UISession, and UISession has a big section in `__init__` that chooses which automator to spin up based upon a number of arguments it is passed.  So it's not exactly a factory per se, but it performs many analogous functions to a factory.

Comment: @sr2222: good, sounds like you have it under control... although I would argue that you should shovel most of the "decide which to use" logic into makeAutomator and just call it to get an Automator object which Foo then uses. ;-)

Comment: So I guess what I said above (excepting @Ben's suggestion below) is the only way to do what I'm looking to do within the (potentially artificially) limited range of action I have defined.  Hrm.  Well, thanks for your suggestions, I appreciate the feedback.